# Can a single privateManagedContext be accessed by multiple threads?

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety

I am implementing some core data sample project. I have defined a mainManagedContext and a privateManagedContext.

Now my question is, "Is it right if I access privateManagedContext using multiple threads?"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with accessing at the same time the static context lead me to a crashes.

So the only solution that I've implemented is to make a copy of the managedObjectContext for each tread where i have to work and make all my function( add/edit/save) with context as parameter:

so in some thread make a copy of context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[localContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:YourStaticManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

and use that context in current thread (add/edit)
then save context:

```
[YourManager saveContext:localContext withBlock:nil];
```

be careful if you need data at the same time when write in one thread and read on other thread better to implement some synchronized access to that staticManagedObjectContext.

Comment: Actually I don't want to create localContext for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to refer to this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

In short, you generally can't refer to the same managed object context from multiple threads.  Unless you set the concurrency policy accordingly.  But, even then, you aren't going to get truly concurrent I/O operations (which is as designed because concurrent I/O is generally slower anyway, among other reasons).

What are you trying to do?